# Replace FreeBSD base clang with ports clang

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, bsd-ports, compiler

FreeBSD 10 was the first release that officially released with Clang as the default, base compiler.

Most ports, unless specially marked, now compile using the base ("pre-installed") clang.

However, clang development is moderately rapid, and so the version of clang in base can be out of date frequently - not only do we have to wait for clang to be imported into base, but then we have to recompile from base (`make world`) to install it; the other alternative for the more enterprising operator would be to navigate the source tree and attempt to rebuild and reinstall just clang.

It would be a lot easier to just use the version of clang that's in ports under lang/clangXX. 
Installing that's easy enough, but then how does one modify the ports infrastructure to use that install of clang instead of the base install of clang?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would treat the ports clang as an alternative compiler, just like when GCC was the default.

As per the FreeBSD [wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BuildingFreeBSDWithClang), add the following lines to /etc/make.conf (if you want to use clang for everything, even ports), or /etc/src.conf (if you want to use clang just for world and kernel):

```
CC=/path/to/clang
CXX=/path/to/clang++
CPP=/path/to/clang-cpp
```

Check where the ports clang binaries where installed under /usr/local and adjust accordingly.